# Running multiple instances of redis with redis-server@.service

Tags: systemd, redis

A redis-cluster involves at least 6 instances of redis. A reasonable minimum size for a failover cluster is 3 nodes. Thus, I want to run 2 instances of redis on the same node (but never the same redis data buckets on the same node twice) for a minimal working example. I've had some trouble getting this setup under ubuntu using the standard configuration tools.

My redis setup also involves/requires something called `redis-sentinel` which I assume also needs change in configuration. The main question is: is one sentinel enough, or do we need two redis-sentinels, two redis-servers? (As `/lib/systemd/system/redis-sentinel@` seems to exist).

Out of the box, ubuntu provides a special `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server@` systemd unit script that can support these extra server(s). What do I need to do to be able to have:

```
systemctl start redis-server@2
```

start my second server?

**In particular**:

- I've added port 6380 to the configuration file as the port at which the second server listens.
- How to clone, edit, point the configuration file(s) and which configuration file(s) need cloning.
- How to configure the sentinel.
- How to ensure redis doesn't put master and slave of the same slots on the same node (defeating the purpose).
- How to ensure that the PIDfile is accessible (by default there's access denied messages as the user redis isn't allowed access to the pidfile in a directory such as `redis-2`).

**Current progress**

I've copied `cp /etc/redis/redis-server.conf /etc/redis/redis-server-2.conf` and `chown redis.redis /etc/redis/redis-server-2.conf`, then edited

```
port = 6380
pidfile /var/run/redis-2/redis-server.pid
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server-2.log
```

So far, the second server merely manages to timeout after 450 seconds (is there a way to shorten this period? it's taking a long time to test/figure this out...) with the rather opaque message found in said logfile `/var/log/redis/redis-server-2.log`:

```
oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
Redis version=5.0.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=671078, just started
Configuration loaded
systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found
Can't open nodes-6380.conf in order to acquire a lock: Read-only file system
```

The first few messages are instant, while the last message is printed shortly after the rest of the message. It typically takes around 2ms for it to pop up. Afterwards, no messages appear for the remaining 89,998ms of the time allocated for startup, after which systemd stops the program (presumably forcefully) and retries 4 more times. (That's where the 450 seconds per attempt come from).

There's no way this `Read-only file system` is the actual problem. `nodes-6379.conf` is easily accessible by the service `redis-server`, which starts without problems.

**Relevant stuff I've tried**

One observation that might be interesting is whether `redis-server@2` will start when the primary `redis-server` is stopped. This has no effect. Whether the former is started or stopped, `redis-server@2` will always fail with this same, cryptic error message, at the same speed.

When starting this second server manually, using the command `/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis-2.conf` it runs, even accepts cluster connections so appears to work. The trouble seems to be with systemd.

Looking further, by changing the `ExecStart` param to

```
ExecStart=strace -f -o /var/log/redis/strace.out /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis-%i.conf
```

and running

```
touch /var/log/redis/strace.out
chown redis.adm /var/log/redis/strace.out
```

there's now an strace output of the process. It spawns a child, which error out with this specific line:

```
811493 openat(AT_FDCWD, "nodes-6380.conf", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

leading me to believe that systemd is using a weird CWD path in the `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server@` unitfile. The same `openat` call succeeds for the default service and for manually starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 450-sec delay is caused by systemd looking in the wrong directory for the pid file.

Redis has poor quality error messages when its files cannot be accessed due to wrong permissions. It doesn't state clearly where it's trying to write/read to. It also appears to ignore some of its configuration and use its own CWD for things anyway, which means that in order to run, Redis needs r/w access to this directory.

That leads to this problem: the `redis-server@.service` script is now wrong, with it using systemd default working directories that don't exist. To solve, add the following line to it under the `[service]` header:

```
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/redis
```

Finally, you need to explicitly state where redis-2 should look for its stuff:

In addition to the `pidfile` and `logfile` params, the `dbfilename` and `cluster-config-file` also need changing, as these are locked by the first Redis process and produce a similar error message if they cannot be accessed. A correct config for `redis-2.conf` would be:

```
port 6380 
pidfile /var/run/redis-2/redis-server.pid 
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server-2.log 
dbfilename dump-2.rdb
cluster-config-file nodes-6380.conf
```